# How to overload 2 versions of operator<< in a C++ class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I am overloading operator<< as follows :

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClass& myobj);
```

Now, I would like to have 2 versions of operator<<, one that would display a short description of my object, and another that would display a longer version.

For example, MyClass could contain information about a client.  In the short version I would display just the name, and in the long version I would display more details like birthday, address, etc.

Is there a way to do that in C++ ?

I know I could have a method of MyClass that receives the stream, but it would be called like this :

```
myObj.DisplayShort(cout)
```

or

```
myObj.DisplayLong(cout)
```

but I would like to stay with a syntax similar to the usual form :

```
cout << myObj << endl;
```

Comment: I am not sure how you want to use the two different descriptions. Would having a member function returning the corresponding summary as a std::string not work? Something like `std::cout << MyClass.summary(true)` (with true of false being detailed or not for Instance)

Comment: what is wrong with `cout << myObj.shortInfo();` and `cout << myObj.longInfo();`? simply provide two string members.

Comment: How would it be decided which version is used when you write `cout << myObj << endl;`?

Comment: your overload of operator<<( ... ) MUST have 2 parameters ,so your only option will be std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClass& myobj) and std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClass * myobj). (strongly not recommended !)

Comment: You could write something like stream manipulator, but I'm not sure if that's possible without global objects. Maybe with some `friend` and `static` trickery. It would be then called like `std::cout << MyClassPrintLong << myObj << std::endl;`

Comment: Write an adaptor. `cout << myAdaptor(myObj);` - the adaptor can keep a `const&` to `myObj` and then you can overload `operator<<` for `myAdaptor` to display `myObj` anyway you like.

Comment: It is possible to create a custom formatting flag and access it from your `operator<<`, an example is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword).

Comment: You could write some wrapper classes, and do `cout << myObj.display_short() << endl;` where `myObj.display_short()` returns a `struct MyClassShortDisplayer {MyClass& which;};` which has a

Comment: You could certainly write a solution of the form `cout << printLong(myObj)` or even  `cout << printLong << myObj`, but you have only made clear some syntaxes you _don't_ like.  What syntax are you looking for?

Comment: @yvesf What is the syntax you desire? It can be done multiple ways. How would you like it to work?

Comment: I didn't have something specific in mind and was open to what would be suggested.  I really like "cout << printLong << myObj" so I will go with that.

Comment: You can't have two overloads of one function that have the exactly same type of arguments.   Since your aim appears to be formatting the output differently, one option is use of a stream manipulator - that way you can change some setting, using the manipulator, and your `operator<<()` can check that setting and change output accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to create a custom formatting flag and a custom manipulator using [`std::ios_base::xalloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc) and [`std::ios_base::iword`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword).

So you have

```
class MyClass {
   static int fmt_flag_index;
   enum fmt_flag { output_short, output_long };
}
```

You initialize `fmt_flag_index` somewhere at the program startup:

```
int MyClass::fmt_flag_index = std::ios_base::xalloc();
```

Here's your custom formatting flag ready to use. Now IO manipulators can set it:

```
std::ios_base& myclass_short(std::ios_base& os)
{
    os.iword(MyClass::fmt_flag_index) = static_cast<int>(MyClass::output_short);
    return os;
}

std::ios_base& myclass_long(std::ios_base& os)
{
    os.iword(MyClass::fmt_flag_index) = static_cast<int>(MyClass::output_long);
    return os;
}
```

And `operator<<` access it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass& f)
{
   switch (static_cast<MyClass::fmt_flag>(os.iword(MyClass::fmt_flag_index)))
   {
     case MyClass::output_short: ...;
     case MyClass::output_long: ...;
   }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyClass myobj;
std::cout << myclass_long << myobj;
std::cout << myclass_short << myobj;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GT8rxvKeT)

Comment: That's cool! I never knew about `iword()`. I've always used adapters, like `std::cout << myclass_long(myobj);` and `std::cout << myclass_short(myobj);` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Same here. Had to make this answer into a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a667K9fEE) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a printing adaptor:

```
class Adaptor
{
    MyClass &adaptee;
    operator <<
}
```

And then you can implement different logic based on:

- Multiple adapter classes
- Single adapter class with a data member
- Single adapter class with a template argument